# How to connect appmaker to a Google SQL over private IP?

Tags: google-app-maker

when trying to connect to my org SQL cloud from app maker, defined to use only private IP it fails:

The default Google Cloud SQL instance is not setup properly. Please ask a G Suite administrator to check the Google Cloud SQL configuration for your domain. Cannot create new database in the default Google Cloud SQL instance.

any specific service needs to be given to appmaker-maestro to make this work ?
if I connect to a custom instance which has public IP enabled it works all well.

thanks for any guidance you might have.